# Can this JSON be turned into a std::map?

Tags: json, visual-c++, mfc, c-strings, stdmap

Sample JSON:

```json
[
 {
   "Hex": "#F0F8FF",
   "Colour": "AliceBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FAEBD7",
   "Colour": "AntiqueWhite"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00FFFF",
   "Colour": "Aqua"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#7FFFD4",
   "Colour": "Aquamarine"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F0FFFF",
   "Colour": "Azure"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F5F5DC",
   "Colour": "Beige"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFE4C4",
   "Colour": "Bisque"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#000000",
   "Colour": "Black"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFEBCD",
   "Colour": "BlanchedAlmond"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#0000FF",
   "Colour": "Blue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#8A2BE2",
   "Colour": "BlueViolet"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#A52A2A",
   "Colour": "Brown"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DEB887",
   "Colour": "BurlyWood"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#5F9EA0",
   "Colour": "CadetBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#7FFF00",
   "Colour": "Chartreuse"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#D2691E",
   "Colour": "Chocolate"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF7F50",
   "Colour": "Coral"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#6495ED",
   "Colour": "CornflowerBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFF8DC",
   "Colour": "Cornsilk"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DC143C",
   "Colour": "Crimson"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00FFFF",
   "Colour": "Cyan"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00008B",
   "Colour": "DarkBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#008B8B",
   "Colour": "DarkCyan"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#B8860B",
   "Colour": "DarkGoldenRod"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#A9A9A9",
   "Colour": "DarkGrey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#006400",
   "Colour": "DarkGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#BDB76B",
   "Colour": "DarkKhaki"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#8B008B",
   "Colour": "DarkMagenta"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#556B2F",
   "Colour": "DarkOliveGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF8C00",
   "Colour": "Darkorange"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#9932CC",
   "Colour": "DarkOrchid"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#8B0000",
   "Colour": "DarkRed"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#E9967A",
   "Colour": "DarkSalmon"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#8FBC8F",
   "Colour": "DarkSeaGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#483D8B",
   "Colour": "DarkSlateBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#2F4F4F",
   "Colour": "DarkSlateGrey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00CED1",
   "Colour": "DarkTurquoise"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#9400D3",
   "Colour": "DarkViolet"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF1493",
   "Colour": "DeepPink"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00BFFF",
   "Colour": "DeepSkyBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#696969",
   "Colour": "DimGray"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#1E90FF",
   "Colour": "DodgerBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#B22222",
   "Colour": "FireBrick"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFAF0",
   "Colour": "FloralWhite"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#228B22",
   "Colour": "ForestGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF00FF",
   "Colour": "Fuchsia"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DCDCDC",
   "Colour": "Gainsboro"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F8F8FF",
   "Colour": "GhostWhite"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFD700",
   "Colour": "Gold"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DAA520",
   "Colour": "GoldenRod"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#808080",
   "Colour": "Grey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#008000",
   "Colour": "Green"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#ADFF2F",
   "Colour": "GreenYellow"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F0FFF0",
   "Colour": "HoneyDew"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF69B4",
   "Colour": "HotPink"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#CD5C5C",
   "Colour": "IndianRed"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#4B0082",
   "Colour": "Indigo"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFFF0",
   "Colour": "Ivory"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F0E68C",
   "Colour": "Khaki"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#E6E6FA",
   "Colour": "Lavender"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFF0F5",
   "Colour": "LavenderBlush"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#7CFC00",
   "Colour": "LawnGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFACD",
   "Colour": "LemonChiffon"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#ADD8E6",
   "Colour": "LightBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F08080",
   "Colour": "LightCoral"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#E0FFFF",
   "Colour": "LightCyan"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FAFAD2",
   "Colour": "LightGoldenRodYellow"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#D3D3D3",
   "Colour": "LightGrey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#90EE90",
   "Colour": "LightGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFB6C1",
   "Colour": "LightPink"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFA07A",
   "Colour": "LightSalmon"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#20B2AA",
   "Colour": "LightSeaGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#87CEFA",
   "Colour": "LightSkyBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#778899",
   "Colour": "LightSlateGrey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#B0C4DE",
   "Colour": "LightSteelBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFFE0",
   "Colour": "LightYellow"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00FF00",
   "Colour": "Lime"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#32CD32",
   "Colour": "LimeGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FAF0E6",
   "Colour": "Linen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF00FF",
   "Colour": "Magenta"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#800000",
   "Colour": "Maroon"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#66CDAA",
   "Colour": "MediumAquaMarine"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#0000CD",
   "Colour": "MediumBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#BA55D3",
   "Colour": "MediumOrchid"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#9370D8",
   "Colour": "MediumPurple"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#3CB371",
   "Colour": "MediumSeaGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#7B68EE",
   "Colour": "MediumSlateBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00FA9A",
   "Colour": "MediumSpringGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#48D1CC",
   "Colour": "MediumTurquoise"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#C71585",
   "Colour": "MediumVioletRed"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#191970",
   "Colour": "MidnightBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F5FFFA",
   "Colour": "MintCream"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFE4E1",
   "Colour": "MistyRose"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFE4B5",
   "Colour": "Moccasin"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFDEAD",
   "Colour": "NavajoWhite"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#000080",
   "Colour": "Navy"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FDF5E6",
   "Colour": "OldLace"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#808000",
   "Colour": "Olive"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#6B8E23",
   "Colour": "OliveDrab"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFA500",
   "Colour": "Orange"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF4500",
   "Colour": "OrangeRed"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DA70D6",
   "Colour": "Orchid"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#EEE8AA",
   "Colour": "PaleGoldenRod"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#98FB98",
   "Colour": "PaleGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#AFEEEE",
   "Colour": "PaleTurquoise"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#D87093",
   "Colour": "PaleVioletRed"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFEFD5",
   "Colour": "PapayaWhip"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFDAB9",
   "Colour": "PeachPuff"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#CD853F",
   "Colour": "Peru"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFC0CB",
   "Colour": "Pink"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#DDA0DD",
   "Colour": "Plum"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#B0E0E6",
   "Colour": "PowderBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#800080",
   "Colour": "Purple"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF0000",
   "Colour": "Red"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#BC8F8F",
   "Colour": "RosyBrown"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#4169E1",
   "Colour": "RoyalBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#8B4513",
   "Colour": "SaddleBrown"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FA8072",
   "Colour": "Salmon"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F4A460",
   "Colour": "SandyBrown"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#2E8B57",
   "Colour": "SeaGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFF5EE",
   "Colour": "SeaShell"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#A0522D",
   "Colour": "Sienna"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#C0C0C0",
   "Colour": "Silver"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#87CEEB",
   "Colour": "SkyBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#6A5ACD",
   "Colour": "SlateBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#708090",
   "Colour": "SlateGrey"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFAFA",
   "Colour": "Snow"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#00FF7F",
   "Colour": "SpringGreen"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#4682B4",
   "Colour": "SteelBlue"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#D2B48C",
   "Colour": "Tan"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#008080",
   "Colour": "Teal"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#D8BFD8",
   "Colour": "Thistle"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FF6347",
   "Colour": "Tomato"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#40E0D0",
   "Colour": "Turquoise"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#EE82EE",
   "Colour": "Violet"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F5DEB3",
   "Colour": "Wheat"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFFFF",
   "Colour": "White"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#F5F5F5",
   "Colour": "WhiteSmoke"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#FFFF00",
   "Colour": "Yellow"
 },
 {
   "Hex": "#9ACD32",
   "Colour": "YellowGreen"
 }
]
```

I would like this as a `std::map<CString, CString>` so that I can take a `#xxxxxx` code and look it up in the map and if it is found, get the description of the colour. This is for ultimately building some HTML syntax in my application.

I know I can manually call `map.emplace(L"#ff0000", L"red");` and have a big list of them. But is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for this JSON data is already similar to what c++ need. Just do a find/replace to remove all occurances of `"Hex":` and `Colour:`. You end up with something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map = {
{
    "#F0F8FF",
    "AliceBlue"
},
 {
   "#FAEBD7",
   "AntiqueWhite"
 },
 {
   "#00FFFF",
   "Aqua"
 }
 //...
};
```

You can use this as

```
printf("map: %s\n", map["#F0F8FF"].c_str());
//output: map: AliceBlue
```

Or you can reverse the map

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> reverse_map;
for (const auto& p : map)
    reverse_map.emplace(p.second, p.first);
printf("reverse_map %s\n", reverse_map["AliceBlue"].c_str());
//output: reverse_map: #F0F8FF
```